# Add checkbox dynamically

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox

how to make the checkbox on the table can be checked? I've the code below to add the checkbox dynamically by using a jquery function. The code below succeed to add the checkbox dynamically, but the problem is the checkbox added by the function can't be checked (disabled).

```
<table id="detail">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="cb[]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the button to add the row:

```
<input type="button" id="addRow" value="ADD ROW" />
```

And this is the jquery function I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addRow").click(function() {
      $('#detail tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#detail tbody>tr:last');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Anyone can help for the code? Thanks... :)

Comment: Do you want the checkbox added be disabled ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please first correct the javascript function !

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addRow").click(function() {
      $('#detail tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#detail tbody>tr:last');
    });
  });
```

And your code works for me means the checkbox is checked (only if you tick last checkbox then your code will clone it)

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8rWa/) or [jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/x8rWa/1/)

Comment: Hi thanks for the code. It works! But who should I set the answer? Your answer is the same with @Sushanthreddy but Sushanthreddy is earlier to post the answer.

Comment: I corrected your JS code but to solve your problem I posted only jsfiddle (and an update).

Comment: Doesn't matter who post first ! the important is the **quality** of answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addRow").click(function() {
      $('#detail tbody tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#detail tbody tr:last');
    });
  }​);
```

check [FIDDLE​](http://jsfiddle.net/87ftk/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#addRow").click(function() {
     var row = $('#detail tbody>tr:last').clone(true);

     // Clear last value
     row.find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);

     // Change name attr
     row.find("#cb").attr('name', 'newNmae');

     //disabled set as a true
     row.find("input:checkbox").attr('disabled', true);

     row.insertAfter('#detail tbody>tr:last');
});
```