# JQuery Date-Picker doesn't work on dynamic form

Tags: jquery, dynamic, datepicker

<< Expanding the question of **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524799/add-checkbox-dynamically)** >>

What I want to do is also add the jQuery function for date selector dynamically to the table. I have this table:

```
<table id="tblDetail">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="a[]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="addinput">Add row</button>
<input type="button" id="removeRow" value="Delete row" onclick="removeRowFromTable();"/>
```

And to make the selection of date on javascript, I've used:

```
$(function() {
  $('#addinput').click(function() {
    $('#tblDetail tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#tblDetail tbody>tr:last');
  });

  $('.datepicker').live("click", function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: '1980:c',
        defaultDate: '-10y'
    }).datepicker('show');
  });
});

function removeRowFromTable() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblDetail');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
```

It works, but when I add the row, the date-picker still show but always return the value to the first row textbox. How to do that?

---

**UPDATE**

Please check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JkSgy/)**.

I found that the code solved the problem (you will have to omit the **ID element** on the datepicker textbox), but it works only when you firstly add the row without choose any datepicker. But when you stop to add the row and start to use the datepicker (fill the whole textbox added previously with the datepicker), then when you add the row again, the datepicker won't work for the newly added rows.

Comment: This is the http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/JkSgy/1. It may helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the id for datepicker. The id must be unique. so You would try with the class name like this

```
<table id="detail">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="date" name="date[]" class="datepicker"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script language="Javascript">
var dates = $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    showAnim: 'slide',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
</script>
```

if you want to add more than one in single function means  try this also

```
$('.datepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Or otherwise you have to add id dynamically to the text box and create a datepicker with the dynamic id

This is the code which solves your problem. You have clone the row so it adds same id when you choose datepicker. now i changed into like this

```
$(function () {

    $('#addinput').click(function () {

        var textbox_add = $('<tr><td><input type="text" class="datepicker"  name="a[]" ></td></tr>');
        textbox_add.appendTo('#tblDetail tbody');

    });

    $('.datepicker').live("click", function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            yearRange: '1980:c',
            defaultDate: '-10y'
        }).datepicker('show');
    });
});

function removeRowFromTable() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tblDetail');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
    if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code. But the code doesn't work. It still return the value on the first textbox on the table...

Comment: how did you get the datepicker value? could you show me code for geeting the value?

Comment: Pls check the fiddle provided above. :)

Comment: datepicker requires either the ID to be unique or the name. You've removed the ID entirely, but your names are all the same "date[]". Your code that adds a row needs to give the new datepicker a unique ID or name.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is an old post.. i go the same problem before.. but i solved it using add another  row. maybe this could help...

example:

## HTML CODE

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="1" id="listtahunan" class="dataTable">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
    <th scope="col">End Date</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="listyear">
  <tr class="row">
    <td><input type="text" name="startDate[]" id="from1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="endDate[]" id="to1" /></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var counter = 2;
 $('#add').click(function(){
       
     var newTxtBoxTR = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr('id','row'+counter);
     
     newTxtBoxTR.html('<td><input type="text" name="startDate[]" id="from'+counter+'" /></td>' + '<td><input type="text" name="endDate[]" id="to'+counter+'" /></td>');
      
     newTxtBoxTR.appendTo("#listyear");
   
 $( "#from"+counter ).datepicker({
  //defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
});
$( "#to"+counter ).datepicker({
  //defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
});
 counter++;
});
});
```

Hope this helped.... regards.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much.. It will be my future reference while I need this code :)